# Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form twocheckoutResponseForm needs updating

Tags: django, payment-gateway

I am trying to add payment gateway in my django web app. I am using 2checkout as my payment gateway. But there is no proper source code where I can get complete flow for integrating 2checkout in the app.Can anyone help me out? I tried to follow the steps in the [link](https://github.com/zikzakmedia/django-tocheckout) but it was not that much help.

Answer (score 7):

Django 1.8+ requires model forms to be explicit about which fields should be included in the form. The library you linked to was updated over 4 years ago and is no longer compatible with latest versions of Django. You can either fork it and fix it yourself, or monkey patch it.

The easiest fix would be [to add `fields = '__all__'`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) to replicate old behavior, but it is recommended to only include fields you expect to use.

[Class to patch](https://github.com/zikzakmedia/django-tocheckout/blob/master/tocheckout/tocheckout/forms.py#L62):

```
class tocheckoutResponseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Ds_Date = forms.DateField(required=False, input_formats=('%d/%m/%Y',))
    Ds_Hour = forms.TimeField(required=False, input_formats=('%H:%M',))

    class Meta:
        model = tocheckoutResponse
        fields = '__all__'
```

But to be honest, seeing the incorrect use of case for all the class and field names makes me not want to use this library. You are best just finding something else that is still actively developed.